# Как сохранить в Room список обьектов?

Tags: java, android, android-room

Для примера, есть у меня класс `Human()` который как один из параметров содержит список `Car()`

```
class Human() {
...//
public List<Car>

...//
}
```

Как сохранить такой обьект?

Я так пронимаю, есть 2 варианта

1)либо из каждого обьекта списка делать стринг используя `@TypeConverter`

2)либо как то использовать one-to-many

Comment: правильно думаете)

Comment: @SviatVolkov правильно насчет первого или второго варианта? Или всмысле и так и так можно?

Comment: можно и так и так. если ваши элементы списка никак не будут обновляться вне основного объекта, то тайп конвертер. если вы хотите хранить отдельно Human и отдельно Car и так чтобы при изменении Car трегирился и Human то надо рилейшны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока, что ответ 2 из этого поста мне нравится больше всего

Может я чего то не вижу, если так пишите в коммнеты

Но мне кажется он самым удобным, так как ты сам сохраняешь как тебе нужно без создания доп обьектов и без в последующем внезапных сюрпризов

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667160/android-room-insert-relation-entities-using-room

1. Just Create a User with Pets (Ignore pets).

   ```
   @Entity
   public class User {
         @PrimaryKey
         public int id; 

         @Ignore
         private List<Pet> petList;
   }
   ```
2. Create Pet.

   ```
   @Entity 
   public class Pet 
   {
       @PrimaryKey
       public int id;     
       public int userId; 
       public String name;
   }
   ```
3. Now Finally in UserDao.

   ```
   @Insert
   public abstract void insertUser(User user);

   @Insert
   public abstract void insertPetList(List<Pet> pets);

   @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id =:id")
   public abstract User getUser(int id);

   @Query("SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE userId =:userId")
   public abstract List<Pet> getPetList(int userId);

   public void insertUserWithPet(User user) {
       List<Pet> pets = user.getPetList();
       for (int i = 0; i < pets.size(); i++) {
           pets.get(i).setUserId(user.getId());
       }
       insertPetList(pets);
       insertUser(user);
   }

   public User getUserWithPets(int id) {
       User user = getUser(id);
       List<Pet> pets = getPetList(id);
       user.setPetList(pets);
       return user;
   }
   ```

Your Problem can be solved by this without creating UserWithPets POJO.

Comment: `abstract` в DAO-методах необязательно указывать, как и `public`.

Comment: Кроме того, методы `insertUserWithPet` и `getUserWithPets` должны вызываться только внутри `database.runInTransaction(() -> {...})`, чтобы между двумя последовательными запросами в БД не произошли какие-то посторонние изменения в этих таблицах.

Answer (score 0):

Я скину вам кусок кода, который использую у себя. Думаю вы сможете разобраться

```
class Account {
@Embedded
lateinit var user: User

@Relation(parentColumn = "email", entity = PurseUser::class, entityColumn = "emailId")
lateinit var userPursers: List<PurseUser>

@Relation(parentColumn = "email", entity = TransitionUser::class, entityColumn = "emailId")
lateinit var userTransitions: List<TransitionUser>
```

}

Модель PurseUser

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = User::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("email"), childColumns = arrayOf("emailId"), onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)), primaryKeys = arrayOf("emailId", "walletAddress"))
class PurseUser {

    var scoring: Double = 0.toDouble()

    lateinit var emailId: String

    lateinit var walletAddress: String

    @TypeConverters(PurseConverter::class)
    lateinit var typePurseEnum: TypePurse

    constructor(scoring: Double, emailId: String, walletAddress: String, typePurseEnum: TypePurse) {
        this.scoring = scoring
        this.emailId = emailId
        this.walletAddress = walletAddress
        this.typePurseEnum = typePurseEnum
    }

    constructor() {

    }

    fun setTypePurse(typePurse: TypePurse) {
        this.typePurseEnum = typePurse
    }
}
```

И метод добавления

```
@Insert
abstract fun insertPurseUser(purseUsers: List<PurseUser>)

@Transaction
open fun insertAccount(account: Account) {
    insert2(account.user)
    insertPurseUser(account.userPursers)
    insertTransitionUser(account.userTransitions)
}

@Transaction
open fun updatePurse(purseUser: PurseUser, purseUser2: PurseUser) {
    updatePurseUser(purseUser)
    updatePurseUser(purseUser2)
}
```

Так же по мне очень удобно можно получать данные пользователя одним запросом.

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = :emailId")
abstract fun getAccount(emailId: String): Maybe<Account>
```

Где метод в моем репозитории

```
  override fun getAccount(email: String): Maybe<Account> {
        return MaybeUtils<Account>().getMaybe(database.accountDao().getAccount(email))
    }
```

Этот метод находится у меня в презентере

```
override fun setAdapterTransition() {
    repository.getAccount(userState.email).subscribe(object : DisposableMaybeAbstract<Account>(context, context.getString(R.string.emailError), context.getString(R.string.emailError)) {
        override fun onSuccess(user: Account) {
            account = user
            mainScreenView.setAdapterTransition(ModelsView.setAdapterTransition(account))
            mainScreenView.setAdapterPurse(ModelsView.setAdapterPurses(account))
            mainScreenView.setAdapterPurseTransition(ModelsView.setAdapterPurseTransition(account.userPursers))
            mainScreenView.setAdapterTransitionSheet(ModelsView.setAdapterTransitionSheet(context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.sheetTransitions)))
        }
    })
}
```

И мой базовый

```
abstract class DisposableMaybeAbstract<T>(private val context: Context, private val onComplete: String, private val onError: String) : DisposableMaybeObserver<T>() {

    override fun onSuccess(t: T) {
        MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, onError, context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorRed))
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, onError, context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorRed))
    }

    override fun onComplete() {
        MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, onComplete, context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorRed))
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется все стало ясно... Мне почему то казалось, что все должно не так работать. Я думал, что есть обьект в котором есть список и сохраняем мы это все как обьект со списком(как бы все вместе). Но нет получается, обьект сохраняется отдельно от списка и получается из базы тоже отдельно от основного обьекта... Не было особо опыта с работы с бд

Comment: Хочу узнать, а что вы думаете об этом ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667160/android-room-insert-relation-entities-using-room который второй. Мне такой вариант больше нравится, но возможно я чего то не вижу. И я не уверен, что он будет работать с CASCADE при удалении

Comment: Мне не нравится второй способ,  я в нем вижу костыль. Тут нет явной связи объектов. А через месяц-два или когда сядет смотреть это другой программист, возникнут вопросы.  Нужно будет документировать, и да насчет CASCADE при удаление тут скорее всего вы правы. А это означает и нужно это еще учесть

Comment: Да, но с другой стороны если список находится внутри обьекта как у меня в вопросе, то нужно создать какой то мапер который будет приводить мой обьект к такой форме как вы указали в своем ответе(то есть вытягивать из него все списки), что тоже требует дополнительной логики и документации, нет?

Comment: Посмотрите выше в ответе. Я добавил изменения. Одним запросом я получаю объект Accout. А в нем хранятся списки других объектов

Comment: Как вы будете сохранять аккаунт если в него добавить допустим поле int ? Вам прийдется делать акаунт @entity , верно?

Comment: Но тогда room покажет вам ошибку, он не может сохранять entity внутри entity или у вас это не так?

Comment: внутри entity, использую @Embedded. Советую вам посмотреть уроки startAndroid про room. Отличная серия уроков

Comment: Мы наверное о разном говорим. Вы не можете использовать @Embeded на простых типах это аннотация для обьектов. Посмотрите еще раз серию уроков про room. Отличная серия уроков)) Попробуйте ради интиреса добавить в ваш класс `Account` поле `int randomNumber` поставте аннотацию над `Account` `@Entity` и попробуйте скомпилировать

Comment: Как минимум нужно тогда добавить  ключ, а так же указать в базе данных таблицу

Comment: С надеждой на то, что вы понимаете о чем я говорю я не стал описывать все пошагово. Да вы правы нужно добавить ключ и таблицу. Но то, что я хотел сказать это то , что в вашем случае не получиться добавить к `Account` аннотацию `@Entitty` даже если добавите таблицу и ключ

Comment: В данном коде вы не сможете добавить скорее всего из-за того что в User я использую ключ. Вот тут похожая ситуация: https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/530-urok-6-room-entity.html

Comment: В общем я сейчас занимаюсь такой же ситуацией. Пока все компилирует. Как проверю по заполнению данных, сообщу вам